# Cocoa - Giving focus to a WebView in an NSStatusItem

Tags: cocoa, focus, webview, mouse, hover

I've set the `view` for my `NSStatusItem` to a `WebView`, but I'm not able to capture `hover` events in the `WebView` because my `NSStatusItem` doesn't get focus, like a normal `WebView` would.

How do I programmatically give my `NSStatusItem` or its associated `view` focus so that the embedded `WebView` will capture mouse events like a normal `WebView`?

Comment: I'm also open to any other way that will allow my WebView to properly detect mouse events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone cares, one way I can think of is to have the `view` for the `NSStatusItem` be a custom `NSView` that overrides the `NSResponder` methods `mouseEntered:`, `mouseMoved:` and `mouseExited:`. Then, I would add the `WebView` as a subview of the custom `NSView`, and each time the mouse moves inside the `NSView`, send the coordinates of the mouse to the Javascript in the `WebView`, which can figure out what element is at the position of the mouse cursor.

Basically, it would be reimplementing mouse hover at its core. Hopefully there's an easier way though.